# How disconnect signals in gtk.builder?

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I connect all signals in [gtk.builder](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbuilder.html) with this:

```
ui_builder = gtk.Builder()
ui_builder.add_from_file('main.ui')
self.win_main = builder.get_object('win_main')
ui_builder.connect_signals(self)
```

How could I block/disconnect any/all signals, please? (And reconnect?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was about to ask the very same question: given that I want to use `glade` to describe my interface and to declare signal names, how do I programmatically disconnect what I can programmatically connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gtk.builder provides connect_signals() as a convenience, once the signals are connected it's up to you to programatically block or disconnect signals.

Here is the PyGTK documentation for both blocking signals and disconnecting handlers:

http://www.pygtk.org/pygtktutorial/ch-advancedeventsandsignals.html

Comment: but this answer just tells us "if you have the handler_id then you can disconnect the signal". and gtk.builder.connect_signals does not provide the handler_id of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in such case, is to connect manually the signal, not with  `gtk.Builder.connect_signals` because this method doesn't return their
handlers ids, and without that handler you cannot manipulate the signal.

In my case was just a couple of signals not big deal.

Answer (score 0):

what I am doing right now: forget about `gtk.builder.connect_signals`.

so after your code:

```
ui_builder = gtk.Builder()
ui_builder.add_from_file('main.ui')
self.win_main = builder.get_object('win_main')
```

I would have something similar to this:

```
list_of_handler_ids = []
import libxml2
doc = libxml2.parseFile('main.ui')
ctxt = doc.xpathNewContext()
signals = ctxt.xpathEval('//signal')
for s in signals:
    handler = getattr(self, s.prop('handler'))
    signaller = getattr(self.win_main, s.parent.prop('id'))
    handler_id = signaller.connect(s.prop('name'), handler)
    list_of_handler_ids.append(handler_id)
```

which seems to sort of work after a first quick check.

Comment: or better yet using lxml, code looks basically the same, but lxml can be installed from pypi